# How do I gradually change jS variable value on cursor position?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to connect a jS Blotter effect to a cursor position function, whereby the cursor position on the page changes the value of one of my parameters. I'm getting the cursor position like this:

```
var immersive = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
immersive.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 
    console.log(y)
}
```

which works. And this is my working Blotter.js:

```
var text = new Blotter.Text("immersive", {
    family: "'Shapiro W00_75 Heavy', Helvetica",
    size: 72,
    fill: "#0a0a0a"
});

var material = new Blotter.RollingDistortMaterial();

material.uniforms.uRotation.value = 252
material.uniforms.uSineDistortSpread.value = 0.08
material.uniforms.uSpeed.value = 0.3

var blotter = new Blotter(material, {
    texts: text
});

var elem = document.getElementById("ahHighlight");
var scope = blotter.forText(text);

scope.appendTo(elem);
```

The problem is I don't want to do this:

```
var immersive = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
immersive.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 
    console.log(y)

if (y == 1) {
// tiny change
} else if (y == 2) {
// another tiny change...
}
```

If i want to gradually effect the `material.uniforms.uRotation.value` parameter based on cursor position how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why about using modulo for this? Based on y's position the value change a bit.

```
value = y % 252;
// 1 % 252 = 1
// 1000 % 252 = 244
```